# Jquery UI resizable image forcing other image to move also in div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

http://jsfiddle.net/maximus392/gcQmM/7/

My problem is that the resizable image is making the other image to move also in the div. I want to prevent the movement of other contents on the div canvas when i resize the image.

Pls suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your images positioned absolutely:

```
img.item { 
    position:absolute;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gcQmM/8/)

Answer (score 0):

> http://jsfiddle.net/gcQmM/34/
>
> ```
> this fiddle is much better i think, and more simple
> ```